# Consume RESTful service located On-Premises from Azure

Tags: azure

My company has several RESTful services that are behind a firewall.  I would like to be able to access these services from the Azure cloud with a client app as if the  service is located in Azure.

For example, if I have an on-premises url like:

`https://onpremiseservice/Customers/1`

I would like to be able to access it from Azure like

`https://mycompany.azurewebsite.net/Customers/1`.

Is this possible? Can I do some kind of URL forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated 26th September 2022*

You have many options, here they are in order of ease of configuration vs performance (ExpressRoute being the hardest to configure but with the best performance).

1. **Use [Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet) it was designed for this use case.**
2. Configure the on prem firewall so that your Azure web app outbound IP's can connect to the on prem API. Then create a Web API in the Azure web app that proxies calls using HttpClient to your on perm API.
3. Use a [Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview)
4. Use [Point-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create)
5. Use [Site-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create)
6. Use [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/expressroute/)

[More information on your options in depth](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/04/07/connection-options-when-building-an-azure-hybrid-cloud-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Use [Azure Service Bus Relays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/).